# How to reset/restart just the console in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

As shown in the screenshot the `Console` seems to have gotten into a strange state. Is there a way to reset it?  As can be seen I've already hit `Stop` several times.

[image]

Is there more generally a way to reset *any* panel in `RStudio` ?

Comment: Can you try CTRL + C as well as ESC?

Comment: `+` signs at the start of the line signify that some expression on a previous line was incomplete (e.g. bracket that wasn't closed off), and R is waiting for the closing bracket or whatever. Pressing <Escape> cancels the input and returns it to normal

Comment: thanks Marius - yea turns out i had pasted some code inside a `for` loop and it was waiting for the closing `}` just like you hinted.  You should put an answer and get some points for your trouble.

Comment: [stuck on "+"](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200792676-stuck-on-)

Answer (score 1):

you can right click while over the console and click reload, this may help